# Print the total length of all "quoted" characters

Tags: code-golf, string, number

## Rules

In this challenge, I'm going to redefine the definition of "quotes" a bit.

- **Quotation marks** (AKA **quotes**) are *any identical characters* used in pairs in various writing systems to set off direct speech, a quotation, or a phrase. The pair consists of an opening quotation mark and a closing quotation mark, *which is the same character(case-sensitive).*
- If there are quote-pairs overlapping each other,

  - If a pair nesting another, both pairs are still valid.
  - If a pair not nesting another, the first starting pair remains valid. The other is no longer considered as a pair.
- When counting quoted characters(length of a pair of quotes),

  - The quotes themselves don't count.
  - Each pair's length is counted independently. Overlapping doesn't affect another.

## Goal

Your goal is to print the total length of all valid quotes. This is code golf, therefore the code with the fewest bytes wins.

## Examples

```
Legend:
    <foo>: Valid quotes
    ^    : Cannot be paired character

Input   : ABCDDCBA
`A`  (6): <BCDDCB>
`B`  (4):  <CDDC>
`C`  (2):   <DD>
`D`  (0):    <>
Output  : 12

Input   : ABCDABCD
`A`  (3): <BCD>
`B`  (0):  ^   ^
`C`  (0):   ^   ^
`D`  (0):    ^   ^
Output  : 3

Input   : AABBBBAAAABA
`A`  (0): <>    <><> ^
`B`  (0):   <><>    ^
Output  : 0

Input   : ABCDE
Output  : 0

Input   : Print the total length of all "quoted" characters
`r` (40):  <int the total length of all "quoted" cha>
`n` (14):    <t the total le>
`t` (15):     < >   <o>       <h of all "quo>
` `  (7):      ^   <total>      <of>   ^        ^
`h`  (0):        ^             ^                  ^
`e`  (8):         < total l>                 ^          ^
`o`  (0):            ^           ^         ^
`a`  (0):              ^            ^              ^ ^
`l`  (0):               ^ ^          <>
`"`  (0):                               ^      ^
`c`  (0):                                        ^    ^
Output  : 84

Input   : Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers
`P`  (5): <eter >
`e`  (9):  <t>     ^      <d a p>           <d p>  ^
`r`  (0):     ^     ^
` `  (3):      ^     ^      <a>    <of>       ^
`i`  (5):        <per p>
`p`  (3):         <er >        ^       ^       ^ <>
`c`  (8):               <ked a pe>       ^
`k`  (7):                ^        < of pic>
`d`  (0):                  ^                 ^
Output  : 40

Input   : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
`h` (27): <ttps://www.youtube.com/watc>
`t`  (0):  <>            ^          ^
`/`  (0):       <>               ^
`w` (14):         <><.youtube.com/>         <4>
`.`  (7):            <youtube>
`o`  (0):              ^       ^
`u`  (1):               <t>
`c`  (0):                     ^      ^             ^
`Q`  (8):                                  <w4w9WgXc>
Output  : 57
```

Comment: @NickKennedy I fixed the rules to be more like actual quotes. I think this is what you expected. Can you review this?

Comment: looks good! Thanks for listening to my feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
œṡ¹¡ḢṖẈ;ß€ƲS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9qZWxsef//xZPhuaHCucKh4bii4bmW4bqIO8Of4oKsxrJT/8OHxZLhuZj//1ByaW50IHRoZSB0b3RhbCBsZW5ndGggb2YgYWxsICJxdW90ZWQiIGNoYXJhY3RlcnM)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts for input from stdin.

```apl
≢∊t⊣{t,←'(.)(.*?)\1'⎕S'\2'⊢⍵}⍣≡⍞⊣t←⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBS8NAEIXv/RVDL2lFExQvClKS1nuLBz30sm62SejaHdOJSxGv2gYiXrwWbK9e@4fmj8SNB1t8MAPv470nUJ/EC6FNUvPyDWtebXhZEpfbZzrm1w@v43c7/lGvOz71@P3zxhufeVxuuNq9cLXl1RdXaxcmF@Xqu9mo4VfYCqP@YNCPwtYhaG4PwsgpdPqXuv5zwzybEVCqgAwJDVrNEkrBTEBoDe3HwpCK2yBTkQtJKp/vm8pZGGboPmZyqmIQgEpOm3IDtCOoEA9LKRHOL4PAWusvTEHFvfKleQisIJn2nq7ikT23F7fJnRz9AA)

`t←⍬` set up an accumulator `t` (for **t**otal)

`⍞⊣` discard that in favour of string input from stdin (symbol: quote in console)

`{`…`}⍣≡` apply the following anonymous lambda until stable (fix-point; previous ≡ next)

`⊢⍵` on the argument

…`⎕S'\2'` PCRE **S**earch for the following, returning group 2 for each match:

`(.)` any character (we'll call this group 1)
  `(.*?)` as few characters as possible (we'll call this group 2)
  `\1` the group 1 character

`t,←` update `t` by append that to `t`'s current value

`t⊣` discard that (the final list of no matches) in favour of `t`

`≢` count the number of characters in that

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

```javascript
f=([c,...a],i=a.indexOf(c))=>c?(~i&&i+f(a.splice(0,i+1)))+f(a):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BT4NAEIXv/opND@1uigtVjNoEG2g92540MR7WYYC1K7vCUPTiX0dIGj1QXzJzeO/ly3tTB1VDpR2dlzbFrssi/gyelFK9eDpSUpcpfj5kHISI7mDFv/V0qucZV7J2RgPywNPzhRBi8MQy6MCWtTUojc15xmdxst5s1kk8E4L5PltcnJ0oDHcsXI7yOOkV9/qFBKcY9/@F20qXxKhARpaUYQbLnApmM6aMYZOPxhKmEwaFqhQQVvURdBOOSNjHbKtd/52GPaZMMYewH2CDYXrHoXN/kHA0pyBy9dL327aVX7ah5hUl2He/VQTF6hCluzZsbx/zJ9gdGVfX3Q8)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                       // f is a recursive function taking either the input string
                            // or an array of characters, split into
  [c, ...a],                // c = next character and a[] = all remaining characters
  i = a.indexOf(c)          // i = index of the 1st occurrence of c in a[] (-1 if not found)
) =>                        //
  c ?                       // if c is defined:
    ( ~i &&                 //   if i is not equal to -1:
      i +                   //     add i to the final result
      f(a.splice(0, i + 1)) //     remove the left part of a[] up to i (included) and
    )                       //     do a recursive call on it
    + f(a)                  //   add the result of a recursive call on a[]
  :                         // else:
    0                       //   stop recursion
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 100 bytes

```
({{<({}<>)<>(({<>(({}({})<>[({}<>)]))(){[{}()](<>)}{}}{}){(<>)})<>{}>{<>({}<<>({}<>)>)<>}<>[{}]}{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JUxBCsMwDPuK6ck@9Aclb9i95OB16VIWEpZ5J5O3p04LQraEpGflI8974k/vqLqgtsXR4hD1omYwud6@J0LS1VzyaLppM5Bev8W0uVGz7M2OxpZdq/gRpt4f9cgCEgNIEU6QQn5LhLIDpwTT918kvCbYIlfeJNRfn/kE)

#### Commented

```
# Loop over each character in input and sum iterations:
({{

  # Evaluate matching quote search as zero
  <

    # Move opening "quote" to right stack
    ({}<>)<>

    # Until match or end of search string found:
    # Note that the character to search for is stored as the sum of the top two entries in the right stack.
    (

      ({

        <>((

          # Character to search for
          {}({})

          # Subtract and move next character
          <>[({}<>)]

        # Push difference twice
        ))

        # Add 1 to evaluation of this loop
        ()

        # If no match, cancel out both 1 and pushed difference to evaluate iteration as zero (keep one copy of difference for next iteration)
        # (compare to the standard "not" snippet, ((){[()](<{}>)}{}) )
        # Then move to other stack
        {[{}()](<>)}{}

        # If a match was found, this will instead pop a single zero and leave a zero to terminate the loop, evaluating this iteration as 0+1=1.

      # Push 1 if match found, 0 otherwise
      }{})

      # If match found, move to left stack and push 0 denote end of "quoted" area.
      {(<>)}

    # Push the same 1 or 0 as before
    )

    # Remove representation of opening "quote" searched for
    # The closing quote is *not* removed if there is a match, but this is not a problem because it will never match anything.
    <>{}

  >

  # Move searched text back to left stack, evaluating each iteration as either the 1 or 0 from before.
  # This counts characters enclosed in "quotes" if a match is found, and evaluates as 0 otherwise.
  {<>({}<<>({}<>)>)<>}

  # Remove 0/1 from stack; if 1, cancel out the 1 added by the closing "quote"
  <>[{}]

# Repeat until two consecutive zeroes show up, denoting the end of the stack.
# (Because closing quotes are not removed, it can be shown that all other zeroes are isolated on the stack.)
}{}})
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

Recursive solution. Find quote groups, count their lengths, and then recursively look for sub-group lengths and sum everything together.

```ruby
f=->s{s.scan(/(.)(.*?)\1/).sum{|a,b|b.size+f[b]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBbsIwEEX3OcUIsUhasFWpmyJRrhBWrUQRsp1JbGFikxnXosDZ02TzvvT035D0bRzb7fqT7iTIqL6UpahK8bKrft5kJShd7g@10g8tyP3ha3vQx@dzzNZ5hA6ZCoiJCZanFbSH5elYYN@M9eB6BrYIHFh58Nh3bCG0oLyHxTUFxmYBxqpBGcaBihqngdrFidGZMzagIKI5z9Es/GQixjifLXOkjZQ5Z3ELiZNGYcJFZsXG7n63zT6/54@v7tvs/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>(s=/(.)(.*?)\1(.*)/.exec(s))?f(s[3])+f(s=s[2])+s.length:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU7LTsMwELzzFVZPNgi7vA4UmShpkSpOLRwAFaQaZ/OgJjbxpoavD444Eg6MtDurGc1o39Reed3WDo8bm0PfF9LLa@qloJxRfpiw55NITHD4BE09Y0lB/ebshR1Fln5zGi/PDTQlVrNpf6Vt460BbmxJi22azReLeZZu2cGIM8yIk2YRacRfuZvf8qqtGyRYAUGLypCfh4gtiDKGTD46i5BPiK5UqzRC60cqIOpkVbu4Xa13kBNFHOjd0DIIJioOnBtNV4jOz4QIIfAv22H3ClzbdxEU6irZy3wdzsPlQ/mo1/8P22V5cX/7dLdMpzHcfwM)

Original approach (64 bytes):

```javascript
f=(s,r=/(.)(.*?)\1/g,t=r.exec(s))=>t?f(t=t[2])+t.length+f(s,r):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY49T8MwEIZ3foXVyabFKQgGikyUtkgVU1sGQIBU41w@qImNfanh1wdHjISBV7obnlfP6d7kQXrlaosnjcmh6wpB/cSJhHJG@XHKnk@TcoLCcfgERT1j4hrTgqLAp7MXNkauoSmxGhe9xmbT7kqZxhsNXJuSFrtsvlguF/Nsx44Gmn4Gmmwek8X85d38xmtXN0iwAoIGpSY/fxFTEKk1GX20BiEfEVVJJxWC8wMnIHKyrm3ctlZ7yIkkFtS@v9IDHYkFawftCtH6WZKEEPiXabF9Ba7MexIkqio9iHwTzsPlffmgNv@Xzaq8uLt93K6yaZS7bw)

```javascript
f=s=>                              // Main function:
 (s=/(.)(.*?)\1(.*)/.exec(s))?     //  If a "quoted" segment can be found:
  f(s[3])                          //   Return the recursive result outside this segment,
  +f(s=s[2])                       //   plus the recursive result of this segment,
  +s.length                        //   plus the length of this segment
 :0                                //  If not: no quoted segment, return 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
œṡḢẈṖ$Ḣ+ɼṛƲ)Ẏ$F¿®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7Fz7csejhro6HO6epAFnaJ/c83Dn72CbNh7v6VNwO7T@07r/BoZVAITfrRw1zFHTtFB41zLU@3M51uP1R05rI//@juaLVHZ2cXVycnRzVY3WgPBCG8hydgMARCJDlXSHMgKLMvBKFkoxUhZL8ksQchZzUvPSSDIX8NIXEnBwFpcLS/JLUFCWF5IzEosTkktSiYqi2VCBbISCzAEgWZCZnp6YoJCoUpCZng3SCBHKAIgWpBQVwHRklJQXFVvr65eXlepX5pSWlSal6yfm5@uWJJckZ9mW2KYHlJuWW4ekRyYHqsVyxAA)

A full program that takes a single argument, the input string wrapped in a list, and returns the number of quotes characters as an integer.